# ¿Qué significa la interrogación después del tipo de dato?

Tags: c#

Qué significa el signo de interrogación en la siguiente declaración de variable:

```
private decimal? monto;
```

Comment: que puede ser nullificable.

Comment: Hola @lucho te saludo, **te sugiero revisar [ask]** y recuerda que como opción para estas preguntas puedes entrar a el [chat], ahí hay varios expertos que te pueden ayudar a solucionar este tipo de dudas, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
private decimal? monto;
```

El `?` indica que la variable puede tomar además de un valor decimal el valor `null`.

Te recomiendo revisar la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) al respecto.

Comment: Downvoter, ¿podrias explicar la razón del voto en contra?

Comment: supongo que es por que es una pregunta que ya existe y para que repetir preguntas con respuestas

Comment: Una cosa es que la pregunta exista, y otra distinta es que la respuesta sea incorrecta.

Comment: es que para eso estan los comentarios yo solo te digo lo que pienso de por que lo hizo ya que por las reglas no puedes contestar cualquier pregunta, facil eso lo googleas y te sale la respuesta que tu das pero bueno cada cabeza es un mundo

Answer (score -1):

Significa que puede aceptar valor `null` la propiedad monto.

La documentación la podes encontrar en este [articulo de microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

saludos